# iOS CoreML mlmodel file auto-generates swift version of model class file

Tags: ios, swift, coreml

I am using CoreML for my current objc project. Normally the .mlmodel file will automatically generate a .h file for me to import the model class in my viewcontroller. But if I import some swift file in the project, the auto generated .h file change to swift version which is not explicit in the project. I can not use it in the objc project. How to make the .mlmodel file auto-generating .h model class in an objc and swift mixed project?

Answer (score 15):

In your project's Build Settings, under "CoreML Model Class Generation Language", choose Objective-C instead of Automatic.

Comment: you totally save my day. Thanks!

Comment: hi @Matthijs, do you know where is the generated model `.swift` file?